# How can i call a pl/sql function with hibernate or jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

1.When I run the following command in order , I can get the result table:

first  run

```
declare
ref clpss2.pck_adapter_total.cursorType;
begin
ref := clpss2.pck_adapter_total.f_get_totals(13605);
end;
```

then run

```
select * from clpss2.temp_totals;
```

the function is :

```
function f_get_totals(nPolDetailID in number)return cursorType
is
ref_cur cursorType;
...
begin
   ...   
   open ref_cur for
   select * from clpss2.temp_totals where policy_detail_id=nPolDetailID;
   return ref_cur;
end;
```

My question is : how can I call this function or store procedure using hibernate or JPA, (not JDBC)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JPA version 2.1 have [support for Stored procedures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.1?). An example on how it works you can find [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures). You can use Hibernate 4.3 which implements the JPA 2.1 specification.